# In repeat section make column invisible

Tags: orbeon, xforms

it's easy to make invisible row in repeat section. But we need to make invisible first column of repeat. How can we make it?

Comment: Is it first column or first row ?

Comment: @KaipaMsarma, first column of repeat section (grid).

Comment: So the first column is invisible on all rows? If so, then you dont need to code that column at all.

Comment: @KaipaMSarma, yes, the first column must be invisible on a table. Actually, this column contain data which user shouldn't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have 4 columns for each row containing the below information,

```
DOJ EmpId   EmpName Department
```

and the node look like this

```
<employee>
<doj/>
<emp-id/>
<emp-name/>
<department/>
</employee>
```

then the xforms:repeat content will look like this

```
<xforms:repeat nodeset="instance('main-instance')/employees/employee" id="employee-repeat" >
<tr>
<xforms:group ref=".[your condition]">
<td>
    <xforms:output ref="doj" />
</td>
</xforms:group>
<td>
    <xforms:output ref="emp-id" />              
</td>
<td>
    <xforms:output ref="emp-name" />                
</td>
<td>
    <xforms:output ref="department" />              
</td>
</tr>
</xforms:repeat>
```

Now, since you does not want to show the first column( in this case doj) on all rows, simply remove the first `<td>` inside the repeat content.

**Update:**

Based on OP Comment, yes we can hide and show instead of removing the code by using `<xforms:group>` tag. Above code is modified to reflect this.

Comment: thank you for your help. You're right. But it's complicated method for author, who don't want remove `<td>` code using "Edit Source" button in Form Builder. Is there more simple approach?

Comment: on the other hand, author of form would be add/remove some data to/from this invisible control. And, of course, it will not be possible, because of removed `<td>` tag.